# Tastypie : How to publish a dictionary using Rest API

Tags: django, tastypie

I am stuck with a problem in python-Django framework. I want to know is it possible to publish a dictionary using a rest api using tastypie. If yes please let me know how. Also any reference link will be appreciated.

```
Sample dictionary:

tupl =[]
dict1={}
tupl.append({"city":"Kolkata"})
tupl.append({"city":"Delhi"})
dict1["location"] = tupl

output Json:
[{"location": [{"city": "Kolkata"}, {"city": "Delhi"}]}]
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have an example here http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html

You need a subclass of a Resource and to override one or more of the ob_* methods

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a `SomeModel` model class and it has `get_dict_field()` function that returns `dictionary`.

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie import fields
from .models import SomeModel

class CustomResource(ModelResource):
    dict_field = fields.DictField(
        attribute='get_dict_field',
        readonly=True
    )

    class Meta:
        queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'someresname'

        # ....
```